# How to prevent docker-compose up from changing folder permissions

Tags: docker-compose, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a WSL2 Ubuntu terminal with docker for windows, and every time I run `docker-compose up` the permissions of the folder that contains the project get changed.

Before running docker-compose:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 12 cesarvarela cesarvarela 4096 Jun 24 15:37 .
```

After:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 12 999 cesarvarela 4096 Jun 24 15:37
```

This prevents me from changing git branch, editing files, etc. I have to chown the folder again to my user to do that, but I would like to not having to do this everytime.